# how to pass multiple parameters javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

```
<?php 
   $a ='a'; 
    $b='b'; 
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a=<?php json_encode($a); ?>;
    var b=<?php json_encode($b);   ?>;
    window.parent.clear(a,b); 
</script>
```

This clear function is defined in js already. When I pass a single variable it goes perfect  but 2 variables it fails.

Comment: Please ignore e  in  starting,it is  nothing

Comment: @ Ashish: You can use the "edit" link under your question to correct things.

Comment: What error do you get? Can you post the clear function?

Comment: var a=<?=json_encode($a)?>; var b=<?=json_encode($b)?>

Comment: You have to show, what is `clear()` supposed to do.

Comment: It depends on the clear function definition, doesn't it? Maybe the function is just defined to take one parameter. Also, `json_encode` is a php function, not javascript.

Comment: Wow! nice mixture of JavaScript and PHP...

Comment: Hey  Clear function  update a page with  values a amd  b

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how that would work even with a single parameter, as your `json_encode` call is in the JavaScript code, not the PHP.

Here's the minimal change version:

```
<?php 
    $a ='a'; 
    $b='b'; 
?>
<script type=text/javascript>
    var a=<?php echo json_encode($a)?>; 
    var b=<?php echo json_encode($b)?>;   
    window.parent.clear(a,b); 
</script>
```

But you can also do this to avoid creating those global `a` and `b` JavaScript variables:

```
<?php 
    $a ='a'; 
    $b='b'; 
?>
<script type=text/javascript>
    window.parent.clear(
        <?php echo json_encode($a); ?>,
        <?php echo json_encode($b); ?>
    );
</script>
```

(I'm assuming the values `'a'` and `'b'` are placeholders, not your actual data.)

Or if you use shorttags:

```
<?php 
    $a ='a'; 
    $b='b'; 
?>
<script type=text/javascript>
    window.parent.clear(
        <?=json_encode($a)?>,
        <?=json_encode($b)?>
    );
</script>
```

...but a lot of people don't, and it looked like you weren't.

---

Side note: Your `script` tag is invalid (though I wouldn't be surprised if most browsers accept it), because you don't have quotes around the `type` attribute's value, and the value contains a `/`. (You can't leave off the quotes if the value has a `/` in it.) E.g:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
<!-- Error here--^        -->
```

Either put quotes around the value:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

...or just leave the `type` off entirely:

```
<script>
```

...as JavaScript is the official default for `script` as of HTML5 and has always been the default on all browsers (even IE) anyway.

Comment: @AshishPandey: Yes, but it's not in the PHP part of it. It's just in the JavaScript. Without `<?php ... ?>`, that text will get sent directly to the browser (where it will fail, because the JavaScript engine doesn't have a `json_encode` function, and if it did, it wouldn't have the variables `$a` or `$b`).

Comment: hey  i  have  corrected  it !but  still  it  dosent  seem  to  work

Comment: I  have  declared clear fuction  with  multiple  parameters  in  js  file ,so  declaration  should  not be a  problem

Comment: @AshishPandey: I never said there was a problem with the function declaration. Are you talking about my thing about the `script` tag? It's definitely wrong. As I said, browsers may accept it anyway, but you should fix it.

Comment: @AshishPandey: Hope this helped! If the answer was something else, the best thing to do is post your own answer to your question (that's perfectly fine here on SO) and then accept it when SO lets you (after two days).

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to run that code?...i don't understand so clearly because I see that you're trying to use php code directly with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you intend to pass an object something like this.

```
<?php 
    $a = array('a','b');
?>
<script type=text/javascript>
    var a=<?=json_encode($a)?>; 
    clear(a); 
</script>
```

If you use:

```
<?php 
    $a ='a'; 
    $b='b'; 
?>
```

You can't json_encode `$a` & `$b` since those are not an arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php 
  $a = array('firstVal' => 'a'); 
  $b= array('secondVal' => 'b'); 
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var a=<?php echo json_encode($a); ?>;
   var b=<?php echo json_encode($b);   ?>;
   console.log(a.firstVal);
   console.log(b.secondVal);
   window.parent.clear(a,b);
</script>
```